# SQL Query for getting distinct domain and count

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I have a Data Extension which has email address. I want to store all distinct domains and counts of these emails in another DE
For eg: I have someth@som.com, test@test.com, 123@test.com.
So my o/p should be:
som.com 1
test.com 2

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not being an SQL guru, I can't tell you whether this is the most efficient way of fetching and counting all the unique domains, but it at least does the job:

```
SELECT RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) as emaildomain ,
COUNT(Email) as EmailCount
FROM   [Your data extension]
WHERE  LEN(Email) > 0
GROUP BY RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))
ORDER BY EmailCount DESC
```

Which will give you this output (in a bad example, with only gmail.com addresses in the DE):
[image]

Comment: Just an addition: When your questions aims towards the system dataviews of salesforce: they most include an own column that is named domain. atleast for open click unsub bounce and so on

Comment: It's not the system data view. Infact I want to see the domain count of the contacts who don't receive an email. It's a custom DE. Thanks for the pointing it though :)